# Editing a DataTable Row & Column VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am dynamically building a DataTable and just adding rows to it as my events fire.

What I wish to do is then update a particular row that is found based on the entry in the first column. I do not wish to do a For Each and then IF statement because my For Each could potentially cycle through tones of rows that it isn't interested in.

Help :/

```
'Call Recorder Variables
Dim retelltbl As New DataTable

Public Sub AlertingEx(direction As Integer, party As Integer, 
        sendingComplete As Integer, csid As Integer, auditType As Integer, 
        signallingMode As Integer, reservedParam7 As Integer, 
        reservedParam8 As Integer, reservedParam9 As Integer, 
        reservedParam10 As Integer, callid As String, 
        calledNumber As String, callingNumber As String, timestamp As String, 
        reservedString5 As String, reservedString6 As String)

    retelltbl.Rows.Add(New Object() {Date.Now, callid})
    Console.WriteLine("Alerting: " & callid & " | " & calledNumber & " | " & callingNumber)
End Sub
```

When a receive a connected Event I wish to then update the retelltbl using the callid to link the 2.

Cheers,

Comment: You're calling Rows.Add(), but you said you want to update. How is the program supposed to know what row to update without going through them?

Comment: You could access a particular row of that datatable using an index.. If you know which row to update, access it directly using the index. The other way is to loop through all the rows.

Comment: Ok, we are working with a DataTable, right?  A DataTable is made up of TableRows.  And TableRows are made up of Columns.  I assume that one of your columns is some sort of Unique Identifier, yes?  As you add a new row, you should also be adding something unique to identify it.  Maybe a GUID, or something.  Is this what callid is?  If callid is unique, then you can add a view to your DataTable, and then use a filter on that view to find the exact your you want. No need to loop through each DataRow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I am understanding you correctly, you need to find a single row in a DataTable, but you don't want to loop through each row to find it.  This is perfectly understandable.  And there IS a way to do it, assuming that you have a way to identify a unique row.  From looking at your code, I'm guesing that "callid" might be a column that will uniquely identity each row?  Is so, you could do something like this:

```
Dim MyFilter As String = "callid=" & callid
Dim MyRows As DataRow() = retelltbl.Select(MyFilter)
```

This would give you an array of DataRows that match the criteria in your filter.  Assuming each callid is unique, the collection would only contain one row, in which case you would access it with:

```
MyRows(0)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Casey,

Cheers for the reply, can I filter on 2 identifiers i.e. CallID and Number?

Comment: Also I have tried using your code and I KNOW there is a certain CallID available in the table however your method does not return me a result. :/

Comment: Yes, you can filter on as many columns as you want. Spend some time  learning about DataTable filters. Google is your friend! As to your second comment... I would suggest going through the code in debug mode and looking at your DataTable with the DataTable viewer. It will show you exactly what data is in your datatable.  VERY handy.